# Что такое API-функция?

Tags: delphi, pascal, терминология

У меня есть самоучитель по Delphi, там почти во всей книге какие-то API-функции.
И ещё вопрос! Есть ли такие функции в Pascal?

Comment: Ну так то перед изучением Дельфи надо понятия хотя бы небольшие по API-функциям получить.
Тем более, раз книга " Delphi. Трюки и эффекты" кажется мне, что там будет много их использования, а Дельфи взята только как среда написания кода

Comment: Эти функции не в Паскале, и не в Дельфи, и не в Си, а в операционной системе. Очень многие языки предоставляют возможность вызывать их. И Паскаль тоже.

Comment: Только что пробовал одну из них в Паскале: не получается!!!

Comment: Там нужно подключить разные модули. В каждой реализации паскаля - свои. Поищи для своей версии.

Comment: В турбо паскале нельзя использовать, т.к. он компилирует только под dos, а нужно под windows. А вот в Free Pascal можно.

Comment: [Все здесь](http://myrusakov.ru/php-api.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это, скорее всего, написано об API-функциях операционной системы. API - Application Program Interface - интерфейс прикладного программирования. В книгах по Delphi часто упоминают про WinAPI, т. е. API-функции ОС Windows. А что за книга (название и автор)?

Comment: Программирование в Delphi. Трюки и эффекты. Александр Чиртик.

Comment: Книга нормальная: там программирование на примерах. Но перед изучением WinAPI лучше изучить саму Delphi: язык и среду, хотя-бы поверхностно.

Answer (score 10):

*API - application programming interface - интерфейс программирования приложений.*

Современные операционные системы не разрешают обычным программ иметь прямой доступ к ресурсам, т.е. устройствам компьютера - дискам,  портам ввода-вывода и т.д. Все это берет на себя операционная система, а для общения с приложениями она предоставляет набор функций, вызывая которые программа может дать ОС команду что-то сделать: прочитать файл на диске, запустить другую программу и т.д. В ОС Windows также через API осуществляется создание графического интерфейса.

Есть и более широкое понятие API - это вообще набор функций, которые какая-либо программа, библиотека, интернет-ресурс предоставляет другим программам для осуществления каких-то действий.